# Error response from daemon: Get http s://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

Tags: docker, docker-machine, boot2docker

I am having virtual box 5.2 on top of Windows 7. I followed docker quick start guide to install docker.[docker for windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)

Since my machine is behind corporate proxy , i set

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://xxx:port
HTTPS_PROXY=https://xxx:port
NO_PROXT="192.168.99.1/24"
```

By passing it while creating docker machine and also did export after machine is up.
'`docker-machine create -d virtualbox  --engine-env HTTP_PROXY="http://xxx:80" --engine-env HTTPS_PROXY="https://xxx:80" --engine-env NO_PROXY="192.168.99.1/24" default`

`docker run hello-world` shows above error.

Comment: I am having the same problem since I recreated the `default` machine today afternoon. I am also behind a corp proxy (I set them in the `start.sh` with `export HTTP_PROXY=...`). I also tried pulling images from the internal registries with the same "does not look like a TLS handshake" error. PS the `docker-machine restart` solution below didn't help

Comment: I tried adding internal registries as insecure with `--engine-insecure-registry` hoping to go around TLS but still the same error

Comment: @mRcSchwering i am having Windows 7 machine. Did u copied boot2docker.iso from C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox to C:\Users\UserName\.docker\machine\machines\default ?

Comment: Yes finally I got it. Yes I am on WIn7. Seems that there was a problem with the `boot2docker.iso` -- as you said. I actually looked for an older version of that .iso and copied it into `C:\Users\User\.docker\machine\machines\default`. Seems that I did a `docker-machine create` at some point which loaded a newer `.iso`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked out for me.
Once installed docker as per instructions given docker quick start and create docker machine 
replace boot2docker.iso at C:\Users\anant.docker\machine\machines\default with the same present at C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox

restart docker

```
docker-machine restart
```

apply environment variable

```
docker-machine env
output :
```

export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"

export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"

export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="C:\Users\anant.docker\machine\machines\default"

export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"

export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"

@# Run this command to configure your shell:
@# eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env)

```
eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env)
```

then to test, try

```
docker run hello-world
```

Answer (score 7):

Just change your `HTTPS_PROXY=https://xxx:port` to `HTTPS_PROXY=http://xxx:port`.

Futher more, if you use the configuration file in directory `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`, then need to change the content existed in `https-proxy.conf` file. after that, run below command to make it effective:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker.service
```

Then your problem should be solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hello everyone, sorry for my English, but from so much research I finally got to work the problem of the Docker in CentOS 7         to run the **Hello-World**

Create a directory in systemd for the docker service:

```
 $ mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

Create the file with the name https-proxy.conf

```
 $ /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf
```

Add the environment variable **"HTTP_PROXY"** and **"HTTPS_PROXY"**:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://(host_name):(port_number)/" "HTTPS_PROXY=http://(host_name):(port_number)/"
```

Restart service Daemon and Docker "

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Now, execute the command, Done.

```
docker run hello-world
```

Answer (score 0):

first check your internet connection is running and then
if you are in docker desktop
simply change the second proxy which is https proxy from https://proxy:port to
http://proxy:port
if you are on linux change the config file to this`{ "proxies": { "default": { "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001", "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001", "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com" } } }`
or change the variable to HTTPS_PROXY   ENV HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy:port"

for more info on linux ***

```html
<a href="https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/"></a>
```

---